# Terraform IPAM Pool: ConcurrentMutationLimitExceeded: There are too many concurrent mutations for the requested resource. Try again later

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Error message

```
│ Error: creating IPAM Pool: ConcurrentMutationLimitExceeded: There are too many concurrent mutations for the requested resource. Try again later.
│       status code: 400, request id: a3895e4a-d7ff-40c8-88bc-2198d8bf8bd0
│ 
│   with module.overlapping_cidr_second_ipv4_scope.module.level_one["us-west-2"].aws_vpc_ipam_pool.aws_pool[0],
│   on modules/sub_pool/main.tf line 6, in resource "aws_vpc_ipam_pool" "sub":
│    6: resource "aws_vpc_ipam_pool" "aws_pool" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: creating IPAM Pool: ConcurrentMutationLimitExceeded: There are too many concurrent mutations for the requested resource. Try again later.
│       status code: 400, request id: a1775b38-dfc1-4c1d-934f-b5f5ad73f1c5
│ 
│   with module.overlapping_cidr_second_ipv4_scope.module.level_one.module.first_pool["us-east-1"].aws_vpc_ipam_pool.aws_pool[0],
│   on modules/aws-ipam/main.tf line 6, in resource "aws_vpc_ipam_pool" "sub":
│    6: resource "aws_vpc_ipam_pool" "aws_pool" {
```

The terraform code

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "= 4.2"
    }
  }
}

variable "cidr" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/8"
}

locals {
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/8"
  # regional_cidrs = cidrsubnets(var.cidr, 8, 8, 8, 8)
}

module "ipv4_scope" {
  # source  = "aws-ia/ipam/aws"
  source = "../.."

  top_cidr = [var.cidr]

  pool_configurations = {
    us-west-2 = {
      cidr   = ["10.0.0.0/16"] # [local.regional_cidrs[0], local.regional_cidrs[1]]
      locale = "us-west-2"

      sub_pools = {
        sandbox = {
          cidr = ["10.0.0.0/20"]
          allocation_resource_tags = {
            env = "sandbox"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_ipam_scope" "scope_for_overlapping_cidr" {
  ipam_id     = module.ipv4_scope.ipam_info.id
  description = "Second private scope for overlapping cidr."
}

module "overlapping_cidr_second_ipv4_scope" {
  # source  = "aws-ia/ipam/aws"
  source = "../.."

  top_cidr      = [var.cidr]
  create_ipam   = false
  ipam_scope_id = aws_vpc_ipam_scope.scope_for_overlapping_cidr.id

  pool_configurations = {
    us-east-1 = {
      name        = "ipv6 us-east-1"
      description = "pool for ipv6 us-east-1"
      cidr        = "10.0.0.0/16" #[local.regional_cidrs[0]]
      locale      = "us-east-1"
    }
    us-west-2 = {
      description = "pool for ipv6 us-west-2"
      cidr        = "10.0.1.0/16" #[local.regional_cidrs[1]]
      locale      = "us-west-2"
    }
  }
}
```

module

```
locals {
  description = var.pool_config.description == null ? replace(var.implied_description, "/", "-") : var.pool_config.description

  name = var.pool_config.name == null ? var.implied_name : var.pool_config.name
  tags = merge(var.pool_config.tags, {
    Name = local.name }
  )

  ram_share_enabled = try(length(var.pool_config.ram_share_principals), 0) > 0
  pool_cidrs        = var.pool_config.cidr == null ? [var.pool_config.netmask_length] : var.pool_config.cidr
}

resource "aws_vpc_ipam_pool" "sub" {
  address_family      = var.address_family
  ipam_scope_id       = var.ipam_scope_id
  source_ipam_pool_id = var.source_ipam_pool_id

  description                       = local.description
  locale                            = var.implied_locale != "None" ? var.implied_locale : var.pool_config.locale
  allocation_default_netmask_length = var.pool_config.allocation_default_netmask_length
  allocation_max_netmask_length     = var.pool_config.allocation_max_netmask_length
  allocation_min_netmask_length     = var.pool_config.allocation_min_netmask_length
  allocation_resource_tags          = var.pool_config.allocation_resource_tags
  auto_import                       = var.pool_config.auto_import
  aws_service                       = var.pool_config.aws_service
  publicly_advertisable             = var.pool_config.publicly_advertisable

  tags = local.tags
}

resource "aws_vpc_ipam_pool_cidr" "sub" {
  for_each = toset(local.pool_cidrs)

  ipam_pool_id   = aws_vpc_ipam_pool.sub.id
  cidr           = length(regexall("/", each.key)) > 0 ? each.key : null
  netmask_length = length(regexall("/", each.key)) == 0 ? each.key : null

  dynamic "cidr_authorization_context" {
    for_each = var.pool_config.cidr_authorization_context == null ? [] : [1]
    content {
      message   = var.pool_config.cidr_authorization_context.message
      signature = var.pool_config.cidr_authorization_context.signature
    }
  }
}
```

The complete module with the repository is located here

https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-ipam/tree/main

I am trying to provision AWS IP Address manager with 2 pools (top level scope) and multiple sub pools. But I get the above error.

Any idea will truly be appreciated

Comment: Was there significant activity in the VPC?

Comment: There was no activity going on in the vpc. I tested the code different aws account still the same error @AllanChua

Comment: The code from the question does not seem to match between calling the module and what the module expects as inputs.

Comment: @MarkoE it was a typo in naming convention. I have updated the code. The link to the complete code is found here



https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-ipam/tree/main